# Apache 2.4 The requested URL "/..." was not found on this server. Why?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have CentOS server with Apache http service. I added wordpress files to `/var/www/html/padbuozyne` directory.

When I try to connect via browser http://myhost/padbuozyne I get

> The requested URL /padbuozyne was not found on this server.

```
httpd -v: Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

**How open it on browser?**

```
configuration files:
/usr/sbin/httpd -V:
...
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
...
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
...


/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
...
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
...
```

Comment: Can you check httpd.conf , it the doc root is `/www/html/padbuozyne` ?

Comment: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has line  `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`

Comment: two options.. can you make the doc root  as `"/var/www/html/padbuozyne"` or put all the files directly on `"/var/www/html"` . Also you've mentioned that you're trying to access, `http://myhost/padbuozyne` whereas `padbuozyne` is directory. Try to access a specific file from directory. e.g., `http://myhost/padbuozyne/abc.html`.

Comment: in "/var/www/html" directory  I have not only padbuozyne directory, my goal for parking more websites on my dedicated server. I added test directory to "/var/www/html" and index.html in it but still show some message when i try  connect to http://myhost/test/index.html.

Comment: Can you share the what message it is ? Can you also check if the apache starts up properly ? any error message ? DNS, firewall , all fine ?

Comment: Message 404 The requested URL /test/index.html was not found on this server. Yes apache work properly ,becouse other site a parked on same server and it work properly, i feel problem is with virtual-hosting configurations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29717/discussion-between-newlands-and-edgaras-karka).

Comment: Virtual Hosts. OK. Have you got a `<VirtualHost/>` section? Does it have a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` that matches the `myhost` you provided in your URL?